# SwiftUI Subsequent View top padding

Tags: swiftui

I have a navigation view and a list. When I load the next view, there is a gap at the top, rather than being inline with the previous view.

I have not set any padding and have tried setting any alignments I can find.

Here is my code. When the Company View is display, it is noticably lower down the screen.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestLookupView: View {
    @State var place = "zipcode"
    @State private var distance = 20.0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("Location")
                        .navigationTitle("Company Lookup")
                    
                    TextField("Location", text: $place)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Distance")
                    
                    Slider(
                        value: $distance,
                        in: 10...100
                    )
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button("Look up") {
                        /* will perform lookup */
                    }
                    
                    Text("\(distance, specifier: "%.0f") miles")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailingFirstTextBaseline)
                }
                
                Section {
                    List {
                        TestRowView()
                        TestRowView()
                        TestRowView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestLookupView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestLookupView()
    }
}

struct TestRowView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: CompanyView()){
            
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Company Name")
                        .font(.headline)
                      
                    Text("Company Address")
                        .font(.footnote)
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Company")
        }
    }
}

struct TestRowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestRowView()
    }
}

struct CompanyView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Company Name")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        Text("Address1, Address2, Address3")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            
            Section {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: FeatureView()) {
                    Text("Services")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
               
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Activities View")) {
                    Text("Activities")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("products View")) {
                    Text("Products")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 struct CompanyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
     CompanyView()
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots showing the difference? Testing your code the tops of the **Location** and **Company Name** cells are the same

Comment: Thanks - have added images showing the drop on the Company View. I would like the Company Name section higher up the screen is possible. I cannot see why it is lower than the Location section on the previous  view

Comment: Thank you. What version of iOS / Xcode are you using? The code above on iOS 16.2 has a large title in the first screen, in your screenshots it's inline.

Comment: XCode - is 14.2, iOS 16.2

Comment: Also, I see your screenshots have a `TabView` that's not in your sample code.. Are you doing some weird like wrapping your `TabView` inside a `NavigationStack`? Please test the code you posted (create a throwaway project if necessary), and confirm the problem

Comment: OK - will do. The issue shows in the canvas as well, while running outside of the Tab View, so I didn;t think that the tabview was relevant. I will rebuild it just with this code and post back later. Thanks

Comment: I have managed to sort this by changing the title like this. 
Text("Location")
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Company Lookup"), displayMode: .inline)
Thank you for your help